# How to do many to many query that returns dynamic number of columns?

Tags: query, pivot, many-to-many

I have 2 tables that have a many to many relationship. An items table and a properties table. They are connected by a junction table. Basic versions of the tables below.

| item_name |
| --- |
| sword |
| helmet |
| axe |

| property_name |
| --- |
| sharp |
| steel |
| wood |

| item_name | property_name |
| --- | --- |
| sword | sharp |
| sword | steel |
| helmet | steel |
| axe | sharp |
| axe | steel |
| axe | wood |

I need a query which sets out information as below so i can export it to illustrator to fill in text.

| item_name | property_name1 | property_name2 | property_name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sword | sharp | steel |  |
| helmet | steel |  |  |
| axe | sharp | steel | wood |

Keeping in mind that the maximum number of properties any single item could have could be a large number so i need the method to automatically generate the right number of columns given the selection criteria. I am using microsoft access so any simple way to do it there is preferred.

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using ?